# In R: Sample from a "totals" column, then subtract 1 from sampled column, store value, and resample

Tags: r

I am definitely not an R coder but am trying to stumble my way through this code. I have a dataframe that looks like this--with 200 rows (just 8 shown here).

```
 Ind.ID V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  Captures
1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   2
2   2   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   2
3   3   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   5
4   4   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   2
5   5   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   2
6   6   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   2
7   7   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   3
8   8   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   2
```

I am trying to sample from the Captures column (which is the sum of the row) and output the `Ind.ID` value. If there is a 0 in the Captures column, I want it to subtract 1 from i (`i=i-1`) and resample--to ensure that I get the correct number of samples. I also want to then subtract 1 from the sampled column (i.e., decrease the Captures value by 1 if it was sampled), and then resample. I am trying to get 400 samples (I think the current code will get me only 200, but I can't figure out how to get 400).

i want my output to be

```
23
45
197
64
.....
```

Here's my code:

```
sess1<-(numeric(200)) #create a place for output

  for(i in 1:length(dep.pop$Captures)){ 
    if(dep.pop[i,'Captures']!=0){  #if the value of Captures is not 0, sample and 
        sample(dep.pop$Captures, size=1, replace=TRUE) #want to resample the row if Captures >1
    #code here to decrease the value of the sampled Captures column by 1. create new vector for resampling?
    } 
    else {
     if(dep.pop[i,'Captures']==0){  #if the value of Captures = 0
        i<-i-1 #decrease the value of i by 1 to ensure 200 samples
        sample(dep.pop$Captures, size=1, replace=TRUE) #and resample
      }
     #sess1<- #store the value from a different column (ID column) that represents the sampled row
    }}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `sum(dep.pop$Captures)` is at least 400 then the following code may meet your needs to sample up to the number of captures for each individual id:

```
sample(rep(dep.pop$Ind.ID, times=dep.pop$Captures), size=400)
```

If you wish to sample with replacement (so you do not need to worry about the total number of captures) but still want to use the number of captures per individual id as sampling weights, then perhaps

```
sample(dep.pop$Ind.ID, size=400, replace=TRUE, prob=dep.pop$Captures)
```